# Python sqlite3 select without repeating field

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

i'm working in python with a sqlite3 database, and I need to get all the data from a date, but I just need the last row from each user. Let me explain myself:
My current code is this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

t = (user, pastTS)
resultPoints = c.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user != ? AND timestamp >= ?", t)
conn.close()
```

The problem with this is that it returns me multiple entries / rows from the same user, when I just want the last one.
Is there any easy way to achieve that or should I analayze the cursor in order to remove the repetitive fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can group by the user and get the maximum timestamp value per user, then join with the `table` and output the results:

```
c.execute("""
    SELECT *
    FROM (
          SELECT user, MAX(timestamp) as MaxTime
          FROM table
          GROUP BY user
    ) t2
    INNER JOIN table t1
    ON t1.user != ? and t1.user = t2.user AND t1.timestamp = t2.MaxTime
""", t)

result = c.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Comment: But that will only give me one result, wouldn't it? I need one result from each user. The database may look like this, for example:
User1        4419
User2        4114
User2        4112
User3        4109

And i need to get the last row of each user

Comment: @Javierd98 gotcha, please check out the updated query.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 1):

To get one output row for each user, use grouping.
To select which row from each group to return, [use MAX()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg):

```
c.execute("""SELECT user,
                    [other fields],
                    MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
             FROM MyTable
             WHERE user != ?
               AND timestamp >= ?
             GROUP BY user
          """, (user, pastTS))
```